# How To Get DIV Coordinates Within HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

Is there a way for me to get the absolute position of a DIV element within a HTML5 Canvas element? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify? There shouldn't be any divs nested inside of a Canvas element, unless you mean a div shown as part of the fallback content of the Canvas not working...

Answer (score 2):

[noVNC](http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) (HTML5 VNC client) has some routines that can determine:

- the actual position of a DOM element on a page: getPosition
- the offset within that DOM element where a mouse click happened: getEventPosition

They should be fairly cross-browser.

You can use those as reference and that might help with your issue:
http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/blob/master/include/util.js#L121

Disclaimer: I made noVNC.

Comment: +1 noVNC is awesome. Thanks for sharing your hard work. keep on rocking.

Comment: Thank you, these routines saved me a lot of headaches.